# Cannot access value of ng-model variable of bind-unsafe-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngsanitize

Inside **showdetailsOfInside()** function value of ng-model variable **namein** and **agein** that is inside **bind-unsafe-html** coming undefined however i have filled text contents into it.I can get value through jquery but is there any way to do it through angular js.

```
<body ng-controller="AppController" class="container">
Name <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" /><br>
Age <input type="text" name="age"  ng-model="age"/><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showdetailsOfInside()">showdetailsOfInside</button><br>
<div bind-unsafe-html="primaryData"></div>
<body>
```

Content of bind-unsafe-html="primaryData"

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="shownName()">inside Basic</button><br> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="showAge()">inside Primary</button><br> 

Name inside <input type="text" name="namein" ng-model="namein" id="nameinside"/><br>
Age indise :: <input type="text" name="agein" ng-model="agein" id="ageinside"/><br>
```

Code of bind-unsafe-html directive

```
dynamicContentApp.directive('bindUnsafeHtml', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
          function(scope) {
            // watch the 'bindUnsafeHtml' expression for changes
            return scope.$eval(attrs.bindUnsafeHtml);
          },
          function(value) {
            // when the 'bindUnsafeHtml' expression changes
            // assign it into the current DOM
            element.html(value);

            // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
            // scope.
            // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
            // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          }
      );
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Directive should return object not function, checkout directive documentation

Answer (score 0):

If i'm right, that's ng-bind-unsafe-html="primaryData"

Comment: It is  bind-unsafe-html.Its user defined directive I have mentioned directive code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamicContentApp.directive('bindUnsafeHtml', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //code goes here 
        };
    }
}]);
```